# xPath query for extracting names that might be in <a> element and might be only in <td> element

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract from a table the names of the cities of a football teams.
I'm using python libraries lxml and requests.
some of the elements contains their names in  name  element form and some only with 
 name

for example, Arsenal form -> belongs to London and the name London placed inside

```html
Element='<tr>
   <td>
      <a href="/wiki/Arsenal_F.C." title="Arsenal F.C.">Arsenal</a>
   </td>
   <td>
      <a href="/wiki/London" title="London">London</a> 
      <span style="font-size:85%;">(<a href="/wiki/Holloway,_London" title="Holloway, London">Holloway</a>)</span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <a href="/wiki/Emirates_Stadium" title="Emirates Stadium">Emirates Stadium</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align:center">
      <span data-sort-value="7004607040000000000♠">60,704</span>
   </td>
</tr>'
```

and Chelsea which also belongs to London but isn't placed in  since the author already gave the href when mentioning London in Arsenal element.

```html
Element='<tr>
   <td>
      <a href="/wiki/Chelsea_F.C." title="Chelsea F.C.">Chelsea</a>
   </td>
   <td>London <span style="font-size:85%;">(<a href="/wiki/Fulham" title="Fulham">Fulham</a>)</span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <a href="/wiki/Stamford_Bridge_(stadium)"
         title="Stamford Bridge (stadium)">Stamford Bridge</a>
   </td>
   <td style="text-align:center">
      <span data-sort-value="7004408340000000000♠">40,834</span>
   </td>
</tr>'
```

currently, my XPath query to get the names is `//table[2]/tbody//tr[position() > 1]//td[2]/a/text()`

but obviously it doesn't give me the name of Chelsea city as I ask for only text places in an element.
Furthermore, I need it to be in the order of the football teams in the table so it can't be in 2 different lists.

is there a neat way to do that?

Comment: Given your two `Element`s, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting The city it's placed it so in this scenario it's London for both...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is your xpath:

```
//tr/td[2]/(text(),a/text())
```

Output:

```
London
London
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options with XPath 1.0. One liner :

```
//tr/td[2]/span/preceding::text()[position()=1 or position()=2][normalize-space()]
```

Output : `London London`

Or use the `|` operator :

```
//tr/td[2]/a/text()|//tr/td[2]/text()[1][normalize-space()]
```

Output : `London London`

Comment: Thanks didnt know about the or operator!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
//td[position()=1 or position()=2]//text()
```

This gets:

> Chelsea London (Fulham)

and

> Arsenal London (Holloway)

You could then use `.split()` to get the separate elements from this